# Perl - Subtracting minutes

Tags: perl

```
minute_end - minute_start
```

Example: I start timing something at 3:50 and it stops at 4:10. Just looking at minutes difference, the difference is 20 minutes, which is what I want. However, 50-10 is 40. How do I account for this situation? I'm sure it's an if statement but I don't know how to start.

Comment: Hint: Convert everything to minutes since start of day, or start of day in 1970, and subtract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, and it's simple. It's what I was trying to think of doing originally but it didn't click until I ran across it while browsing for an answer.

If I do `minute_end - minute_start` and the answer is negative, I just add 60 minutes to get the correct answer.

i.e.:

```
10 - 50 = -40
-40 + 60 = 20
```

Comment: How do you determine the difference? Wouldn't you want to do this automatically? My advise: do as Miller suggested above.

Comment: @royskatt Then show me how to do it by getting two local times, not constant times

Comment: What do you mean with "two local times"?

Comment: @royskatt. Localtime_start (minute_start) and Localtime_end (minute_end). I don't know how else to elaborate? My original reply seems plenty descriptive on what I mean. Miller's answer to my question using `'3:50'` is used as a constant. I don't want the time as a constant, I want `$start` and `$stop` as local instant times, when they are called.

Comment: unaccept the answer maybe to get more attention by more skilled people than me :)

Comment: That works fine as long as your timer doesn't run for more than 1 hour.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should be keeping track of things using [`time`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html) from the very beginning?

However, you can parse those strings using [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) to calculate the difference:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my $start = Time::Piece->strptime('3:50', "%H:%M");
my $stop = Time::Piece->strptime('4:10', "%H:%M");

my $diff = $stop - $start;

print $diff->minutes;
```

Outputs:

```
20
```

Comment: Can I use this `time::piece->strptime` method when getting two local times?

Comment: `strptime` is going to assume UTC unless it is provided with additional information.  However, as long as you're dealing with differences and treat all your times the same, this SHOULDN'T be an issue.  This is not a perfect solution though.  If you're just trying to keep track of a process during execution, just use `my $t = time`.  And if you need the string representation of that epoch value, just use `localtime($t)->strftime("%H:%S")`

Answer (score 2):

This is rough, but probably adequate.

```
my $start_time = time;

# ...

my $end_time = time;
my $seconds_run = $end_time - $start_time;
my $minutes_run = $seconds_run / 60;
```

For much more precise timing, see [Time::HiRes](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can get assign current localdates like this, I modify miller's version:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $time1 = strftime("%H:%M", localtime(time));

# do something or wait

my $time2 = strftime("%H:%M", localtime(time));

my $start = Time::Piece->strptime($time1, "%H:%M");
my $stop = Time::Piece->strptime($time2, "%H:%M");

my $diff = $stop - $start;

print $diff->minutes;
```